# High power in A/A test, interpretation?

Tags: python, statistical-power, random-allocation

Randomization has already been executed and two groups have already been assigned, where treatment observations and control observations are captured by df1, df2 respectively.
**Note**: Treatment exposure has not been administered yet.

Randomization appears to have done a good job despite the heavily tailed distribution, but maybe this is okay thanks to the large sample size and central limit theorem?

```
Treatment: mu=420, std=178.77, n=2001
Control:   mu=418, std=169.07, n=1999
```

From my research, it appears that in [t-test context](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.power.tt_solve_power.html), I need the difference of means scaled by pooled standard deviation. But because I have not administered treatment yet, this is an A/A test!

```py
from statsmodels.stats.power import tt_solve_power
def power(df1, df2, metric):    
    arr1 = df1[metric].to_list()
    arr2 = df2[metric].to_list()
    
    n1 = len(arr1)
    n2 = len(arr2)
    n = n1+n2
    
    mu1 = np.mean(arr1)
    mu2 = np.mean(arr2)
    
    s1 = np.std(arr1)
    s2 = np.std(arr2)
    
    pooled_sd = (s1**2/n1 + s2**2/n2)**(0.5)
    diff = (mu1-mu2)/pooled_sd
    
    pwr = tt_solve_power(
        effect_size=diff, 
        nobs=n, 
        alpha=0.95, 
        power=None, 
        alternative='two-sided'
    )    
    return pwr
```

When I run this analysis, I see that diff equals 0.45 and I have 100% power. This tells me (a novice admittedly) that in terms of Cohen's Distance, my A/A effect size is 0.45 standard deviations away from 0... Not great! And for my power to be so high, this seems like an indictment of the randomization process.

Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: I may be missing something here, but why do you want to conduct power analysis, when you've already decided your sample size? Power is useful for design, not for analysis. To me, it looks like what you're doing here is redundant with simply conducting a t-test between the two groups before administering the treatment. But others may have other views about it, so take my comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: We're limited to the 4000 units, so alternative sample sizes are out of the question, unless we selected an arbitrarily smaller subset. Why I conducted power analysis post-randomization? Not included here is that this is a stratified design where we've blocked on several features. So it's not simply shuffling.

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation of the [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance) is wrong and is too small:

```
 . power twomeans 420 418, n1(2001) n2(1999) sd1(178.77) sd2(169.07) alpha(0.05)


Estimated power for a two-sample means test
Satterthwaite's t test assuming unequal variances
H0: m2 = m1  versus  Ha: m2 != m1

Study parameters:

        alpha =    0.0500
            N =     4,000
           N1 =     2,001
           N2 =     1,999
        N2/N1 =    0.9990
        delta =   -2.0000
           m1 =  420.0000
           m2 =  418.0000
          sd1 =  178.7700
          sd2 =  169.0700

Estimated power:

        power =    0.0653

. power twomeans 420 418, n1(2001) n2(1999) sd(`=sqrt(((2001-1)*(178.77)^2 + (1999-1)*(169.07)^2)/(2001+1990-2))') alpha(0.05)

Estimated power for a two-sample means test
t test assuming sd1 = sd2 = sd
H0: m2 = m1  versus  Ha: m2 != m1

Study parameters:

        alpha =    0.0500
            N =     4,000
           N1 =     2,001
           N2 =     1,999
        N2/N1 =    0.9990
        delta =   -2.0000
           m1 =  420.0000
           m2 =  418.0000
           sd =  174.1862

Estimated power:

        power =    0.0652
```

Your power to detect $\Delta = -2$ is about 6.5%, so your telescope will generally not detect a difference this small (as expected in an AA test since you are near the trough of the power curves with a min power of 5%).

Comment: Where does N1/N2 come into play?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 N2/N1 is just the ratio of sample sizes, so $\frac{1999}{2001}=.9990005$. It's redundant but helpful when you have unequal allocation.